# What is allowed with the new EASA SPL license?

Tags: easa-regulations

Are you allowed to fly for profit with SPL? If I have understood correctly, SPL is to LAPL(S) as CPL is to PPL, but with no extra requirements over LAPL(S), but I have problems believing this.

Assuming I have understood the rules correctly, I can upgrade my MGPL to LAPL(S)+TMG and therefore to SPL+TMG with no extra effort. After doing the conversion and flying PIC for 75 hours, I would legally be allowed to ask the passengers to pay for my flights. This seems to be too far from the current rulings that I have trouble believing this.

```
SPL = Sailplane Pilot License
LAPL(S) = Lightweight Aircraft Pilot License (Sailplane)
CPL = Commercial Pilot License
PPL = Private Pilot License
TMG = Touring Motor Glider
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know very little about this, but it looks like you can fly commercially with an SPL if you pass an additional checkride. This is from the [UK CAA](https://www.caa.co.uk/General-aviation/Pilot-licences/EASA-requirements/PPL-SPL-BPL/SPL-requirements/), and the same wording is quoted on a bunch of European gliding organization sites:

> You cannot operate commercially, or receive any kind of payment, until
>   you:
>
> 1. Are 18 years of age or over
> 2. Have completed 75 hours of flight time or 200 launches, after your licence has been issued
> 3. Have passed a proficiency check with an examiner

[EASA's Part-FCL guidance](https://www.easa.europa.eu/system/files/dfu/AMC%20and%20GM%20to%20Part-FCL.pdf) defines what the additional checkride includes:

> **AMC1 FCL.205.S(b) SPL — Privileges and conditions**
>
> CONTENTS OF THE PROFICIENCY CHECK FOR THE EXTENSION OF SPL PRIVILEGES TO EXERCISE COMMERCIAL PRIVILEGES ON A SAILPLANE

Note that it calls it an "extension" of SPL privileges, which strongly implies that an SPL by itself doesn't allow commercial privileges. There is one exception, which is that an instructor can be paid to instruct with just an SPL. The CAA site says:

> The exception to this is for holders of a SPL with instructor or
>   examiner privileges, who can be paid for the following:
>
> 1. Flight instruction
> 2. Conducting skill tests and proficiency checks
>
> for the LAPL (S) or SPL and any associated ratings and endorsements.

Comment: Nice job resurrecting an old question with a good answer!